# android homescreen widget AppWidgetProvider onreceived function intent action and extras are gone/null

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-widget

the code seems fine but not sure the reason why the onreceived function of AppWidgetProvider have intent action null and no extra data that the app puts.

AppWidgetProvider code:

```
public class Widget_2_6 extends AppWidgetProvider{

    private AlarmManager alarm;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        Log.e("onReceive -- Widget_2_6", "onReceive -- Widget_2_6: action: " + intent.getAction());
        boolean from_boot = intent.getBooleanExtra(BootCompleteBroadcastReceiver.FROM_BOOT, false);
        if(from_boot)
        {
            Log.e("onReceive -- Widget_2_6", "onReceive -- Widget_2_6: onupdate start");
            Log.e("onReceive -- Widget_2_6", "onReceive -- Widget_2_6: onupdate end");
        }
        else
        {
            Log.e("onReceive -- Widget_2_6", "onReceive -- Widget_2_6 not from boot: onupdate start");
            Log.e("onReceive -- Widget_2_6", "onReceive -- Widget_2_6 not from boot: onupdate end");
        }
        super.onReceive(context, intent);
    }
```

BootCompleteBroadcastReceiver:

```
public final static String FROM_BOOT = "FROM_BOOT";
    cn = new ComponentName(context, Widget_2_6.class);
                Intent intent_widget_2_6 = new Intent(context, Widget_2_6.class);
                intent.setAction(INTENT_FROM_BOOT);
                intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, manager.getAppWidgetIds(cn));
                intent.putExtra(FROM_BOOT, true);
                context.sendBroadcast(intent_widget_2_6);
```

androidmanifest.xml:

```
<receiver android:name="com.example.linktogoogleplay.Widget_2_6">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE"></action>
                <action android:name="com.example.linktogoogleplay.FROM_BOOT"></action>
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                android:resource="@xml/my_widget_provider_2_6" />
        </receiver>
```

I tried using the android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE as intent action but still recevied null action and no extra data that the app puts.

(NOTE:) needs to update widget to latest data on boot and not using the old data. also the same bootboradcast receiver will run when time is changed (since its need to get latest from server)

the bootBroadcastreceiver is working as it can get the timechange action just he appwidgetprovider part is not working.

please let me know if something is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, got it working. the part were its wrong is the following:

```
cn = new ComponentName(context, Widget_2_6.class);
                Intent intent_widget_2_6 = new Intent(context, Widget_2_6.class);
                intent.setAction(INTENT_FROM_BOOT);
                intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, manager.getAppWidgetIds(cn));
                intent.putExtra(FROM_BOOT, true);
                context.sendBroadcast(intent_widget_2_6);
```

and it has to be the following code (not sure why this works but no extra has been sent still, at least this time the action is sent to the receiver as well instead of null).

```
Intent intent_widget = new Intent(INTENT_FROM_BOOT);
            intent.putExtra(FROM_BOOT, true);
            context.sendBroadcast(intent_widget);
```

but of course getting of the appWidgetIds will be on the onreceive of the appWidgerProvider class.